# Problems with merging branch back to trunk in SVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

We're just starting with SVN (were using CVS before :shame:) and I have a problem with merging my branch back to trunk.

I've created Branch1 from trunk, made some changes and merged it back (without any problem). 
Then I decided to make another branch for second feature, and I made it from Branch1 by mistake. (I should've made it from Trunk).

[image: branch tree]

Now I'm at the X point on my picture. Branch2 is finished and I'd like to merge it back. 
But if I try merging Branch2 to Trunk I get lots of `tree conflicts`. I easily can merge Branch2 back to Branch1, but then again there are `tree conflicts` when merging Branch1 to Trunk.

No changes were made in Trunk directly, neither on Branch1 after it was merged back.

So, my question: is this situation normal for SVN? Am I doing something wrong (I'm just starting :)).

I use latest TortoiseSVN, and I'm doing merge by choosing Merge - "Reintegrate a branch"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Reintegrate the branch" option is useful for regular work, but because you did something irregular (branch from branch) it is not best option anymore. Use option "Merge a range of revisions", because there you can specify exactly the revisions you want merged. Pick only those revisions that make a Branch2 (use log to figure them out).

Comment: Yes, even I had similar issue. When You create a branch out of tab, remember the revision number (say xxx) for the next check in done inside trunk. While merging give merge range as "xxx - HEAD"

Answer (score 0):

I can give you a clue about the Tree conflicts, you should to check the svn:mergeinfo about the conflict files to see whether the SVN do a repeated merge(SVN decides which revision to merge by checking the svn:mergeinfo).